# Java: Why method is not called when inside the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

i have a method :

```
public String getPresentValue(ObjectIdentifier oid) throws Exception {
    ReadPropertyRequest rpr = new ReadPropertyRequest(oid, PropertyIdentifier.presentValue);
    ReadPropertyAck rpa = (ReadPropertyAck) localDevice.send(isa, null, 1476, Segmentation.segmentedBoth, rpr);

    return rpa.getValue().toString();
}
```

That works perfectly when i call it outside of the thread, but when i try to call it inside of the thread, nothing happens.

Why this happens ?

Update:

```
public void active(Supervisory supervisory) {

       //.. my code above is just simple maths

        System.out.println("presentValue in the thread" + getPresentValue(oi));


        ScanAO scanAO = new ScanAO();

        Thread threadAO = new Thread(scanAO);
        threadAO.start();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


    class ScanAO extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {

                for (ObjectIdentifier oi : oisAO) {
                    System.out.println("presentValue in the thread" + getPresentValue(oi));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: What do you mean by calling the method in the thread?  My guess is that this method is never called.

Comment: Can you provide more code?  The answer is almost certainly going to be that your thread isn't running...we just have to figure out why that is.

Comment: *All* code is executed in a thread. You can't call a method "outside of the thread". If you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would make life considerably easier...

Comment: Have you called the `start()` method for your thread?

Comment: Hey partner, you might want to avoid having empty catch blocks especially if you want to know why things are going wrong. At least print a stacktrace.

Comment: @toto, i'm calling the thread, you can see in my code above.
@stevevls, @Jon, Ted, sorry for the lack of information, i update the post.

Comment: Also, I only see you calling the getPresentValue method once in the code above (indirectly via Thread#start()).  Where is the other time you call it?

Comment: @Hovercraft, you was righ dude, that's was an exception launched:
"com.serotonin.bacnet4j.exception.BACnetException: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed"

But i don't know why is closing the socket, if i call the same method outside of the thread works fine.

Comment: For fun you could try running your code in the current thread: just change `threadAO.start();` with `threadAO.run();`.

Comment: @toto, you're awesome man, thanks dude, it works now !
Thanks by the help!
By the ways, why this happen ?

Comment: No!  It shouldn't work.  It was just a test to see what is wrong.  You are not using threads at all by using `run` instead of `start`.

Comment: @toto, the thread isn't working...

Comment: You should not be doing these things manually, you should be using the classes in `java.util.concurrent` to manage your threads, tasks and executions.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be with "oisAO" ? If your getPresentValue() works outside the thread it should probably work inside the new thread. It might be what you are passing into the function.

Comment: it's the socket exception, that is given inside the thread:
"com.serotonin.bacnet4j.exception.BACnetException: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed" But i don't know why is closing the socket, if i call the same method outside of the thread works fine."

Comment: What is "localDevice" ? bluetooth?

Comment: I don't know much about sockets... I don't know if there is something thread dependent about them, but I would doubt so.  What does `getPresentValue` do?

Comment: @toto, getPresentValue gets the value of temperature device to me.

Comment: if you're communicating with a device you might wanna try putting a little delay in the for each loop

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: when you call the code with `.start()` (with multi-threading) you get an exception and when you change `threadAO.start()` to `threadAO.run()` (without multi-threading) it works properly?

Probably `oisAO` is not synchronized between threads: the original thread modifies the state of oisAO (closes the socket) before the new thread created by `.start()` can do its job.  To identify if this is the problem, you could try adding a `threadAO.join()` (pause the current thread until the new thread is done) right after `threadAO.start()`.

If this is the problem, you should give more thought to find a correct solution since just pausing the original thread might give you some performance issues.  If you pause the thread it's not really multi-threaded, but basically just code running on two threads sequentially.